# Видеоплеер на основании урока в NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Создал видеоплеер [на основании видеоурока](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcYPIpT2VRY&nohtml5=False). Код:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.media.ControllerListener;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.*;

public class VideoPlayer extends javax.swing.JFrame implements  ActionListener, ControllerListener {
    File file;
    Player player;
    Component controlcom;
    Container con;

public VideoPlayer() {
    initComponents();         
}                       

private void initComponents() {

    filechooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    jMenu1.setText("Файл");

    jMenuItem1.setText("Відкрити");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("Вихід");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 745, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 350, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}                     

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    new Start().setVisible(true);

}                                          

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try{getFile();
    createFile();}
    catch(Exception e){}

}                                          

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                        
     Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
    setSize (sSize); 
    setResizable(false);
}                                 
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VideoPlayer().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}        

private javax.swing.JFileChooser filechooser;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;

public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce) {
    try {
        con = getContentPane();
        if (ce instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent) {
        Component visualcomponent = player.getVisualComponent();

        if(visualcomponent!= null) {
            con.add(visualcomponent,BorderLayout.CENTER);}
            controlcom = player.getControlPanelComponent();}
            if(controlcom!=null){
                con.add(controlcom,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            }
                con.doLayout();
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }

private void getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
   filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
    if(file.exists()){
    throw new FileNotFoundException();}
}

private void createFile() {
 try{player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(file.toURL());
 player.addControllerListener(this);
 player.realize();}
 catch(Exception e){}
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

В конечном итоге файл не открывается ни `MPEG`, как на видео, ни как-либо ещё.

Ошибка

> Unable to handle format: MPEG, 1280x720, FrameRate=29.9, Length=1382400

Comment: а ошибки пишет какие-нибудь? можете кусок stacktrace'а показать?

Comment: ошыбок внутри програмы нету в консоли ничего странного только время выполнения и все....не понимаю что за stacktrace?

Comment: исправил видео запускается звук идет но картинки нету теперь

Comment: покажите что пишет в runtime exception